# Customizing route model binding key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm calling a route with a variable appended to it's end, like this:

```php
Route::get('/user/{user}', 'UserController@listUser');
```

That points to a controller with a method like so:

```php
public function listUser(User $user){
   dd($user);
}
```

That's working just fine; if I go to `www.example.com/user/3`, Laravel will automatically fetch me the user with id = 3

But I need to change that URL to something like this: `www.example.com/users/nickname` using a different property of the `User` model.

If that's possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you need to define in your `User` Eloquent model the following method:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'nickname';
}
```

You can read more about it in [Route Model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 10, you could also do the blow

```
<?php
use App\Models\User;

Route::get('/user/{user:nickname}', function (User $user) {
    return $user;
});
```