# how to display a name instead of an Id in a URL?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a route that's look like this `/collections/1`  and I want it to look like this `/collections/name` that instance name is stored inside my database and it is unique, I want it to showen in the URL instead of the Id

Here is my Route:

```
Route::get('/collections/{id}', [SousCategorieController::class, 'show']);
```

this is my controller code :

```
public function show(Sous_categorie $sous_categorie, $id)
{

    //dd($id);
    $count = DB::table('produits')->select('produits.sous_categorie_id')->where('produits.sous_categorie_id', '=', $id)->get();
    //return response()->json($count);
    $s_marque = DB::table('produits')
        ->select('marque')
        ->join('sous_categories', 'sous_categories.id', '=', 'produits.sous_categorie_id')
        ->whereIn('sous_categories.categorie_id', [$id])->get();
    //dd($s_marque);
    $f_categorie = DB::table('sous_categories')->select('*')->where('categorie_id', '=', $id)->get();
    $s_produits = DB::table('produits')
        ->select('produits.*', 'sous_categories.categorie_id as laravel_through_key')
        ->join('sous_categories', 'sous_categories.id', '=', 'produits.sous_categorie_id')
        ->whereIn('sous_categories.categorie_id', [$id])
        ->paginate(8)->withQueryString();
    //dd($s_produits);
    $product = Produit::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(12)->withQueryString();
    $prods = Produit::with('souscategories')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(8)->withQueryString();
    $categories = Categorie::all();
    $sous_categorie = DB::table('sous_categories')->select('*')->where('categorie_id', 'like', '%' . $id . '%')->get();
    //$s_produits = DB::table('produits')->select('*')->where('sous_categorie_id','like','%'.$id.'%')->get();
    //return response()->json($s_produits);

    return view('collections.components', compact('sous_categorie', 'id', 'f_categorie', 'categories', 'prods', 'product', 's_produits', 's_marque', 'count'));
}
```

Well I tried a various solution like overriding the name using `getRouteKeyName` like this:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'nom';
    }
}
```

and changing the route like this:

```
Route::get('/collections/{collection}', [SousCategorieController::class, 'show']);
```

**But! Am still getting the same route with id** http://127.0.0.1:8000/collections/1 instead.

Please help me!
thanks

Comment: Please show your view where you're generating the URL

Comment: am not generating the url in the view !!

Comment: Then how are you creating the URL? Where are you getting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/collections/1`? All you've shown so far are the routes files.

Comment: Have you tried `Route::get('/collections/{nom}', [SousCategorieController::class, 'show']);`?

Comment: I have edited my question I am new to laravel if you can give me a general response maybe I'll get it ?

Comment: If you mean `/collections/1` works instead of `/collections/name`, then you need to actually search the data based on the name. Every query I see in your show function seems to be going off the id field instead of the name field.

Comment: am getiing that ID from this anchor href="/collections/{{ $categorie['id'] }}" I need the Id to use it for filtering based on that Id what I want is to change it in the URL if possible without affecting my code .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customizing route model binding key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472426/customizing-route-model-binding-key)

Comment: sadly no that didn't help

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding) (emphasis mine):

> Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions **whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name**. For example:
>
> ```
> use App\Models\User;
>  
> Route::get('/users/{user}', function (User $user) {
>     return $user->email;
> });
> ```

So assuming you are referring to a `Sous_categorie` model in the URL, you need to define your route like this:

```php
Route::get('/collections/{collection:nom}', [SousCategorieController::class, 'show']);
```

And your controller method like this:

```php
public function show(Sous_categorie $collection): View {
...
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note, there are many potential problems with this code that I can see just from the limited code in the question. Unnamed routes, using query build joins instead of relationships, non-standard names for models, and what looks like some very inefficient and repetitive database queries.